# DotNetNuke C# version

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, dotnetnuke

Is there a C# version of DotNetNuke? And how secure are this program to use for my companies intranet?

Comment: Check from dotnet nuke website...http://www.dotnetnuke.com/

Comment: There is now http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/160/threadid/369100/scope/posts/Default.aspx

Comment: From DotNetNuke 6.0 onwards, the core has now been switched to C#.  So the question now is 'Is there a VB.NET version of DotNetNuke'

Answer (score 4):

The point is : why would you want a C# version?  The only time you'd be delving into the core code is to either investigate a bug or create a fix.  All other modifications (modules, extensions, etc) can be coded in whatever language you like.  Any time you're modifying the core code, unless you're fixing a bug, you're doing it the wrong way.

A talented C# developer should have no trouble parsing the VB.NET Code if trying to understand how the system works.  And if you're developing new stuff, then write it in C# if you prefer.  I write all my DNN extensions in C#, without exception.

Comment: This answer still applies, but now is reversed.  With the release of DotNetNuke 6.0, the entire codebase has been switched to C#.  So my comment still applies - if you're changing the source code, you're doing it the wrong way.   You can still write extensions in whatever .NET language you prefer (and now have options for Razor as well) and any decent programmer will be able to read and understand the source code.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. *Dotnetnuke* is built using VB.NET. Shaun Walker once commented once on

> **[Why isn't there is a C# version of Dotnetnuke?](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/118/threadid/18782/scope/posts/Default.aspx)**

But you can build modules on any **`CLR`** compliant language. I once worked on *Dotnetnuke* for [bbcaudiobooksamerica.com](http://www.bbcaudiobooksamerica.com/). The security is well implemented with *Microsoft Enterprise Library*. As you can see on their website, there are well known brands are using it widely which tell us that this is a safe product.

However, it depends on your security parameter what exactly you mean by this. But, IMHO, I would say this is very much safe product design.

I'd recommend you some very useful resources:

- [adefwebserver.com](http://www.adefwebserver.com/dotnetnukehelp/)
- [dnncreative.com](http://www.dnncreative.com)

in terms of Dotnetnuke learning.

Answer (score 2):

Dotnetnuke 6 is now in C# but like everyone mentioned it should not make a difference. DNN6 and DNN5 for that matter are secure enough for company intranet in my experience. I actually stumbled upon this as I am developing my own company's intranet in DNN6. Much cheaper and more customizable than other alternatives like sharepoint in my oppinion

Answer (score 1):

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/118/postid/18782/scope/posts/Default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Right now, there are published packages of the C# source for version 5.4.1 and 5.4.2.  The team is working on adding this packaging to our automated build process so that new packages can be created quickly once the conversion has been done.  A normal turnaround should be just a few days after each regular release.

[Read the entire story...](http://muneebbaig.blogspot.com/2010/05/dotnetnukednn-source-in-c.html)

Answer (score 0):

DotNetNuke 6.0, which was recently released is not completely written in C#.

http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com